# SP Initiated SSO With Google as the IdP using x.509 Cert: null. That's an error

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, x509

I have successfully set up SP Initiated SSO with Microsoft, Auth0, and others. However I have searched, dare I say scoured, the internet to find what the following error means when sending a request to Google for a SP Initiated SSO with Google as the IdP using SAML x.509 Cert.

```
null. That's an error. Error Parsing the request, No SAML message present in the request That's 
all we know.
```

That appears on the screen after the request. I have tested the SAML Login from the Google site and the response comes back fine with a blank relaystate but I'm pushing that in the request. There are users setup, the application is a Web and mobile app with user access set to On for everyone.

For Microsoft I found that for the relaystate to work it had to be first in the request and that the request had to be set as samlRequest not just request.

Does anyone have an idea what the Google error is for?

Answer (score 0):

Finding there are many idiosyncrasies with the SSO Assertion across IdPs, this is another one. The error displayed by Google means that SAML needs to be capitalized. Hence samlRequest will not work it has to be a capital SAML.